# Is a UK spouse visa a "Family" visa or a "Settlement" visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

The form for renewing a UK spouse visa asks the question "What type of visa, leave to remain or other permission do you have to be in the UK?" (as of October 2019). It lists multiple choices of which only "Family" and "Settlement" seem likely candidates.

Unfortunately "Spouse" or "Spouse/Partner" is not one of the choices and there is conflicting information online about whether a UK spouse visa is a "Family" or "Settlement" visa.

How should an applicant answer this question and reassure themselves that they have the correct answer by referring to information provided by the UK government?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel SE! Questions about immigration are better suited at our sister site: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ they might be able to answer this question better :)